# How to access datastore information (Interactive Console)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am right now working in a project where I have two GAE servers. One for development, and the other one for production.

So I needed to access the datastore to run some queries because I need some high level information about the entities we have. The way I did on the development server was by the " URL/_ah/admin ", and there I used the Interactive Console to run my queries in the server.

But the reality is obviously that I need to run that queries in my production server, I tried to acces there the same way by "myapp.appspot.com/admin/interactive" but I am getting a "Page not found", I cant acces either with " URL/_ah/admin ".

So I looking for the easiest way for me to be able to run that queries, by now it seems that I have found two posible ways that I would like to check with you.

- First, it seems that I could active that Interactive Console by:

`- url: /admin/.*
script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
login: admin`

And then I would have acces on the URL "myapp.appspot.com/admin/interactive". Is that correct?

- Second, I have also read about the remote_api and using the remote_shell as an Interactive Console with the server. Would that be harder? Can someone of you link me a guide to do that?

I havent tried anything yet, because I must be sure of what I am going to do since this is a live project.

Thanks a lot,

Jose.

Comment: Do I understand your question? The admin console is at: https://appengine.google.com/

Comment: You can also incoperate this code in your project, to run an interactive shell, where you can execute Python code:
http://shell.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks voscausa, I checked that too and it was a good option as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only made for the development server.

You can find all the code that runs it in the [source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py) and then use them as [custom admin console pages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Administration_console_custom_pages).

For example, in `app.yaml`, place

```
admin_console:
  pages:
  - name: Interactive Console
    url: /admin/interactive
```

and for the URI

```
handlers:
- url: /admin/interactive|/admin/interactive/execute
  script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
  login: admin
```

since the interactive page relies on a POST handler in execute.